# How to enable multiple row selection by mouse in gtk.glade treeview?

Tags: treeview, pygtk, rows, glade, multipleselection

How to enable multiple row selection by mouse  , I use :

```
 selection.set_mode(gtk.SELECTION_MULTIPLE)
```

but the multiple row selection is enabled only by keyboard (shift + arrowup/down)

Answer (score 0):

The option is called "Rubber Binding" , present in the  `properties > general` tab, the default is "no", I just sign it to "yes" - it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SELECTION_MULTIPLE, you need to use signal name "selected-rows-changed".
eg.
widget.connect("selected-rows-changed", your_callback_method)